# How to tell what libass version is already installed and how to update it

Tags: software-installation, 13.04, video, smplayer

How can I fint out the current version of libass installed and how can I update it to the latest install it from scratch?

I have Ubuntu 13.10 and SMplayer installed, and I'm facing some problem in rendering ass files with SMplayer. I'm trying to figure out the cause of this problem.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if you have `libass` installed try in your terminal,

```
apt-cache policy libass
apt-cache policy libass-dev
```

It will show the version of the package as well. To install `libass` enter in terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install libass-dev
```

If your smplayer is correctly installed try to update `libass` as,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libass-dev
```

Comment: Let us know if you have any problem in rendering `ass` files with `mplayer` from command-line using `-ass` option. See [`man mplayer`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/mplayer.1.html) for more. SMPlayer is only front-end of mplayer

Comment: it apperared that it wasn't installed from the begining, but even after installing and updating it, smplayer can't render the ass files nad i installed the mplayer also but it gives me error and doesn't work
please instruct me to use ~-ass~ option

Comment: I found out the problem, it's in the encoding of the subtitle, i changed the default subtitle encoding into UTF-8 and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure universe repository is included in your **sources.list** file

Use gedit to edit the file if necessary using the following command:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then update using

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you can install libass using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libass-dev
```

Comment: i searched the sources list but couldn't find the word universe repository at all, is that what you mean?
sorry for my ignorance but i'm new to ubuntu and try to understand bit by bit